# sort array by date,inside the same array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a blogging site in codeigniter.In which the blog is to be listed in the last one first order.ie the last one will be on top.Here in my application variable $blogs contain all the blogs to be listed and the date_created.$blogs will display the blogs,but not in the required order.Now I want to sort the blog by the date_created value.

the main model function that return the blogs is here

```
public function LoadAllBlogs(){

         $blogs = array();

         $this->db->select('id');
         $this->db->from('blog');
         $q=  $this->db->get();                                 

         foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
               $blog = new Blog();
               $blog->loadWithLatestPublishedEntry($row->id);
               $blogs[] = $blog;
         }

     return $blogs; //contain all the blogs entry and the date in which blog is created
}
```

can anyone help me.....

Comment: what does your array look like

Comment: http://us3.php.net/usort is your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to need to add an ORDER BY clause to your query so they are sorted by your database. It's pretty simple, pass the `order_by()` function a field name and either **asc** for ascending or **desc** for descending.

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('blog');
$this->db->order_by("date_created", "desc");
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: You are listing the values from table.but currently I have all the values and date in an array.Is it possible to sort the array using the date in the same array.

Comment: If you allow the database to sort for you (which is often times more efficient), then in your foreach loop you will be getting the records in the correct order without the need to sort the array you are creating.

Answer (score 1):

this sounds to me that you need a custom function that will compare each two posts and using php uksort ( array &$array , callable $cmp_function ) will do the job.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Answer (score 0):

@cillosis is right - use order by query

but as you intend NOT to go that way you can try the following -

I don't know what does blog array look like, I assume your date value is something like - `"Y-m-d"`

```
 foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
               $blog = new Blog();
               $blog->loadWithLatestPublishedEntry($row->id);

               $time = strtotime($blog->posting_date);

               $blogs[$time] = $blog;
         }

ksort($blogs); //Oldest first
krsort($blogs); //Latest first
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

//Just a side note - when using strtotime - keep this in mind -> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php